# CNContactViewController discard message Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, localization, cncontactviewcontroller

I have same issue as described in this post

[CNContactViewController iOS 13 Discard Message and Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58978172/cncontactviewcontroller-ios-13-discard-message-and-keyboard)

but i'm working with xamarin
and i've added Localizable.strings like this:

[image]

and content in this file:

[image]

Any way I still cannot make it work and accepted answer in the link above does not work for me.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPD:**

the problem is that the text of discard action sheet looks like this and it is not human readable. adding Localizable.strings into Base.lproj didn't help

[image]

Comment: please describe the problem in your post, don't just link to another post

Comment: Can you please add some code or a screenshot to describe the problem you are facing in Xamarin? The keyboard overlapped the field or the localized strings?

Comment: I created a new project and just open the CNContactViewController, everything works well on my side. I can't reproduce the issue. I don't have Localizable.strings file in my project.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT your answer didn't help me, also i'm not alone with this issue

Comment: OK, I want more information to reproduce the issue so that I can help better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, after long search, i`ve found a solution.

to make it work i've added to info.plist values described in official xamarin documentation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/localization/

[image]

and now it works perfectly. but it is not obvious solution

PS: and for the future, Dear commentators, don't answer in such manner: "I created a new project and just open the CNContactViewController, everything works well on my side. I can't reproduce the issue" - It doesn't bring any useful information. better no answer than answer like this.

Comment: You can mark this answer (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) which will help more people with same problem:).